# LED dimmer for high current applications

Tags: led, pwm, 555, dimmer

[image]

Hi Guys .. I am designing a few panels using LEDs for backlighting. Some of these panels have over 20 leds, using a 5v power source. So only one of these panels can draw around 500mA alone. I am planning on using the same PSU to power them all, but need a dimmer circuit to dim them all at once, but most of the dimmer circuits I have seen can only really do lower current draw, i.e. 2N2222 can only handle 800mA.

Any idea if this is possible with one high current dimmer, or do I have to build multiple dimmers ?

Comment: oh just to mention, the dimming needs to happen using only one pot for all panels, so not sure multiple dimmers would be suitable ?

Comment: Please post the schematics or at least a link to your LED dimmer circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Pulse width modulation (PWM) is the most efficient way to do this. The basic principle is that you cycle the LEDs on and off at a speed fast enough that the eye can't detect a flicker - say 50 times a second. By varying the % on-time from 0 to 100% the LEDs can go from 0 to 100% brightness. The  advantages are:

- The power circuit is very simple.
- No power is used while their off.

We need to know what is going to control the dimmer if we are to provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a circuit like this one (from [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/led-light-bar-hookup/example-circuits)): (operated from +5V only)

[image]

Use a CMOS version of the 555 (eg. TLC555) rather than the NE555, and reduce R3 to 100 ohms.

Q1 must be a logic-level MOSFET such as an [AOD476](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOD476.pdf). The circuit as described will easily handle several amperes.

Comment: Since the 555 is running from 12V, surely any MOSFET that's fully on at Vgs=10V will do,  not just a logic level one?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Intention is to run the entire circuit from +5. For +12 any MOSFET and NE555 will work okay.

Comment: Then Spehro's advice is good, and the 555 should be OK on 5V.

Comment: But be aware that you will be radiating like crazy at harmonics of the PWM frequency. Relatively high currents and long leads.

Comment: Doubles as a jammer. ;-)

Comment: not if you put an inductor in the path and thus provide a constant current source

Comment: @JonRB In that case, a catch diode would be necessary or the MOSFET is going to get very hot from avalanching.

Comment: well yes, you would need an additional freewheel diode (and maybe a TVS if this is over a harness that could break) but it solves those issues. Plus gives smoother light

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks for that, sounds like a good idea. when you say several amperes .. how much do you think ? thanks for all the quick answers, however most of the stuff you guys talk about is still all new to me :)

Comment: Depends on the heatsink, switching losses, etc. I didn't calculate it exactly. But 4-5A should be no problem with those parts- it's a 25A MOSFET with fairly low on resistance.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, PWM is the most efficient method to drive the LED's.

I am just including this to expand on the concept, especially if there is any harness involve.

The use of an inductor ensure a constant current to the LED's as oppose to a pulsed current.

By including a sense resistor you could include a simple control loop to maintain current as the load characteristics change (increased V due to temp)

Two sets of "freewheel" diodes are shown. The 1st is the diode that is used to commutate the current from the FET (to maintain current flow through the inductor). The second as part of a Zener+diode stack is for safety if the load goes open-circuit.

NOTE: the zener/TVS needs to be sized to dissipate the energy within the inductor. It would only conduct during a failure situation and thus it does not need to be sized for continuous operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frR9u7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As far as using the same psi for everything, i would multiplex the banks of LEDs. This way you only power one at a time, but they would all "appear" on but you would only power one at a time